# How to extract strings after second dot

Tags: notepad++

How to extract strings after second dot to third dot

```
randomstringkdfidjfidjf.randomstringsdfodjfuodjf.randomStringIneed1414.data
randomstringkdfi32djfidjf.randomstringsd425fodjfuodjf.randomStringIneed54gsg.data
randomstringkdfjfidjf.randomstringsd4djfuodjf.randomstringIneedDFdFeg.data
randomstringkdfjfi645djf.randomstringsd42314djfuodjf.randomStringIneedfwer23f.data
```

for example from:

```
randomstringkdfidjfidjf.randomstringsdfodjfuodjf.randomStringIneed1414.data
```

I want to have only:

```
randomStringIneed1414
```

Comment: How do you want to do this? using a programming language? by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the cursor at the beginning of the file press ctrl+h then use

the regular expression: `(?-s)^(?:[^\.]*\.){2}([^\.]*).*`

and replace with:
`\1`